# How does `bind` work with `Meteor.bindEnvironment`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am a bit confused about the behavior of `bind` with `Meteor.bindEnvironment`, as well as the scoping of `this` with `Meteor.bindEnvironment`. For example, [with arrow functions, arrow functions should maintain the outer scope](http://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/01/a-guide-to-es6-arrow-functions/):

> Essentially it allows you to create an anonymous function with the contextual value of “this” being the scope of the function being that of the outer function that the arrow function is being defined in.

So, when I use the following code, it *appears* to work, but the `console.log` seems to say `this` is the scope of Meteor.

```
Cylon = new EventEmitter();
Cylon.messages = new Mongo.Collection('_cylon_messages');
Cylon._commands = net.connect(Settings.connection);
Cylon._createConnection = function (name, connection) {
  let socket = net.connect(connection, Meteor.bindEnvironment(() => {
    this.messages.insert({ name: name, message: 'connected'})
  }));
  socket._name = name;
  return socket;
}
```

Another example I've been having trouble understanding is using bind in callbacks that require `Meteor.bindEnvironment`. For example:

```
Cylon.execute = function (routine) {
  check(command, String);
  let future = new Future();
  let done = future.resolver();
  this.once('End', Meteor.bindEnvironment(done.bind(null, routine)));
  this._commands.write(`XQ#${routine}\r`, 'utf8');
  future.wait();
  this.removeListener('End', Meteor.bindEnvironment(done.bind(null, routine)));
  return future;
}
```

How does `Meteor.bindEnvironment` work with bindings of `this` to a function? Is there a proper usage?

Answer (score 2):

### What is an Arrow Function?

This is a *really* confusing and verbose sentence:

> Essentially it allows you to create an anonymous function with the contextual value of “this” being the scope of the function being that of the outer function that the arrow function is being defined in.

It could be made easier to understand by condensing it to more terse language:

> It allows you to create an anonymous function that is bound lexically to the scope in which it is defined.

________

### [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) Explained

There is no `console.log` in the examples you have provided - presumably you placed a `console.log` within the arrow function given to `bindEnvironment`, as follows:

```
let socket = net.connect(connection, Meteor.bindEnvironment(() => {
    console.log(this);
    // this.messages.insert({ name: name, message: 'connected'});
}));
```

Indeed, `this` in the example above would be a reference to whatever the execution context is of the arrow function. For example:

```
this.stillInScope = true;
let socket = net.connect(connection, Meteor.bindEnvironment(() => {
    console.log(this.stillInScope); // => 'true'
}));
```

However, let's say we changed the arrow function to an anonymous function. On *invocation* it will not maintain access to the execution context that is present at its time of *declaration*:

```
this.stillInScope = true;
let socket = net.connect(connection, Meteor.bindEnvironment(function () {
    console.log(this.stillInScope); // => 'undefined'
}));
```

So, if the current execution context of this example is the Meteor object, then the arrow function will be lexically bound to the Meteor object:

```
// this instanceof Meteor === true
let socket = net.connect(connection, Meteor.bindEnvironment(() => {
    console.log(this instanceof Meteor); // => 'true'
}));
```

________

### The [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) Method Explained

Let's discuss why you would use `bind` to understand what is being achieved in your second example.

#### First argument to `bind`: execution context

Using `bind` on a method produces a new function that is *bound* to the execution context defined by the first argument. Let's say we run this in the browser where the global execution context is `window`:

```
let method = function () { 
    console.log(this);
};

method(); // => window

let boundMethod = method.bind('Hello'); // `this` now becomes 'Hello'
boundMethod(); // => 'Hello'
```

This binding can never be changed; not by invocation within a bound function or even by subsequent calls to `bind`.

#### Subsequent arguments to `bind`: default arguments

In the example you have given `bind` is really only being used as a shorthand. We can know this because the execution context given is `null`, indicating that `bind` is being used only for the way that it applies *default arguments* to a function:

```
// with `bind`
Meteor.bindEnvironment(done.bind(null, routine))

// without `bind`
Meteor.bindEnvironment(function () {
    done(routine);
});
```

________

### How does `bind` work with `Meteor.bindEnvironment`?

And finally, to answer your question, `bind` doesn't 'work with' anything per se. [`Meteor.bindEnvironment`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/832e6fe44f3635cae060415d6150c0105f2bf0f6/packages/meteor/dynamics_browser.js#L31) takes the function given to it and binds it to an execution context that is maintained by a closure, where the method `bindEnvironment` was initially defined.

[An explanation of the purpose of `Meteor.bindEnvironment` on GitHub](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/465#issuecomment-10167217):

> The idea of bindEnvironment is so that, when passing callbacks to non-Meteor code, you can keep them running in the current context. On the server that includes the current fiber. So if you're finding yourself outside of a Fiber on the server, you're probably not calling bindEnvironment enough!

**By giving it a function that is *already* bound (either as an arrow function or by passing a manually `bind`ed function), you are preventing it from changing the execution context of the function.**